# jQuery autocomplete inside onKeyup function

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need to attach results from a jQuery function.

When the user types in the search field, a function is called and data is returned from my database.

I can see the returned data using alert function

```
<input type="text" name="symbol" id="symbol" required="required"  onkeyup="findmatch();">
```

The jQuery function called is below

```
function findmatch() {
  var symbol= document.getElementById("symbol").value;

  $.post("portfolio/searchStock.php",
      {
        search:symbol
      },
      function(data,status) {
        alert(data);
      });
}
```

I need the data returned to be attached as an autocomplete, I have tried using the following within the function.

I don't understand why it doesn't work

```
$( "#symbol" ).autocomplete({
                source: data
        });
```

The php file echoes data as below

```
    if (isset ($_POST['search'])){
        $search = $_POST['search'];
        if(!empty ($search)){
            $query="select * from companylist where symbol like '".mysql_real_escape_string($search)."%'";
            $query_run = mysql_query($query);

            while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
                $symbol = $query_row['symbol'];
                echo $symbol;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also paste the format in which the data is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format the output of the db call:

```
while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
    $symbol[] = $query_row['symbol'];
}
echo json_encode($symbol);
```

Then, you need to parse the returned data.

```
var sourceData = [];
var arrData = $.parseJSON(data);
foreach(x in arrData)
{
    sourceData.push(arrData[x]);
}
$( "#symbol" ).autocomplete({
            source: sourceData
});
```

Comment: He also needs to keep in mind his data needs to be formatted as:[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ] or [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]

Comment: Thank you for this, need to wait 3 hours to post my answer as i am new  here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$( "#symbol" ).autocomplete({
                'search':function(event,ui){
                var newUrl="portfolio/searchStock.php/abc/"+$("#symbol").val();
                $(this).autocomplete("option","source",newUrl)
                },
                'source':[]
    });
```

and in php

```
  function abc($search ){  


 if(!empty ($search)){ $query="select * from companylist where symbol like '".mysql_real_escape_string($search)."%'"; $query_run = mysql_query($query);

    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){

       $new_row['label']=htmlentities(stripslashes($query_row['symbol']));
     $new_row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($query_row['symbol_id']));
    $row_set[] = $new_row; //build an array
  }

 }echo json_encode($row_set);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the replys, this seems to work. Array needed encoded and parsed from php side
JavaScript File

```
    function findmatch(){   
    var symbol= document.getElementById("tSymbol").value;   
    $.post("portfolio/searchStock.php",
    {
      search:symbol
    },
    function(data,status){
    var arrData = $.parseJSON(data);
    $("#tSymbol").autocomplete({
         source: arrData
    });
    });     
}
```

searchStock.php

```
if (isset ($_POST['search'])){
```

$search = $_POST['search'];
    if(!empty ($search)){
        $query="select * from companylist where symbol like '".mysql_real_escape_string($search)."%'";
        $query_run = mysql_query($query);

```
    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
        $symbol [] = $query_row['symbol'];

    }
    echo json_encode($symbol);


}
```

}